# ¿Cómo incrementar una fila a un dataset?

Tags: python

Tengo un ciclo *while* que llena un *dataset* con el texto que guarde en una variable, lo que quiero es ingresar ese texto en una fila del *dataset* sin tener que copiar el texto sino llamando a la variable.

Tengo este código:

```
pregunta=['Tengo un problema al intentar....']
NewDataset= pd.DataFrame(pregunta,columns=['NewBody'])

i=1
while i <= 599:
      NewDataset= NewDataset.append({'NewBody':'Tengo un problema al intentar....'},ignore_index=True)
      i+=1
```

Comment: Lo que quiero es reemplazar el ['NewBody':'Tengo que...'] y en su lugar llamar a la variable Pregunta

Comment: Ahh bueno imagino que el texto es el de la variable `pregunta`, en todo caso solo reemplaza el texto por la variable `NewDataset.append({'NewBody': pregunta}`

Comment: ¿Es eso lo que quieres?, o tal vez no entendí bien tu problema jeje

Comment: Eso mismo es lo que quiero.Lo intentare Gracias